# Bottom half of laptop screen occasionally flickering black. Size of black area varies

Tags: windows-8.1, lenovo-laptop, laptop-display

I just bought a new laptop the other day. Lenovo Yoga 2 13. During use, the lower half of the screen is turning black. It's almost like a pop up in that it appears, and any interaction with the machine makes it disappear. I can't screen shot it so I don't think it's software related. I've updated my graphics drivers but that hasn't helped. I've also done a clean install of Windows 8.1 and am still having the same issue. I've attached an image to represent what I see. There seems to be no consistency with the size of the black area but it never goes more than half way up.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you connect an external monitor via the VGA/HDMI port? If this works fine then it may be the LCD connector. If you get the same then you may have a graphics card problem. A clean install of the OS rules out malware foul play! Either way, you may want to consider taking it back for the supplier to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hardware issue. Perhaps some of the pins/connections of the graphics chip to the motherboard are making an intermittent connections and dropping out the bottom rows during refresh. Or some connection from there to the LCD is bad. 
You might be able to demonstrate this by slightly flexing the case (emphasis on slightly) or pressing on the keyboard hard enough over the graphics chip (varies on laptops) to slightly push the chip down. 
Also try tilting the screen to rule out screen cable problems.
In any case, you can well enough effort to rule out SW and time to return it.